# Preserve datatype in a cell in Excel when doing search and replace

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010, type-conversion

A webquery is pulling all image names from a directory into excel sucessfully

Using Replace via vba to replace "_lg.jpg" and ".jpg" which works fine on the whole range imported

However in a case where the image is "2496-6-4_lg.jpg" removing the "_lg.jpg" causes excel to interpret the new value as a date 6/3/2496 even if I first format the cells as text

I have tried any number of setting changes within the QueryTables.Add(Connection:= part of the code
It seems like

`.PreserveFormatting = True
.WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
.WebDisableDateRecognition = True`

might affect the final result but changing any of them don't prohibit the image names from converting to dates when the extension is removed

Additionally I am explicitly iterating through the range using

```
For Each cell In Range("E2:E" & lastPhoto)
        cell.Select
        ActiveCell = ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1
        Next cell
```

Which does force them to a text format since each cell is already formatted as text, but these that have already converted to dates are not helped by that

All of this is to do comparisons of text output from a db query to look for missing image names

Everything works well except these misinterpreted dates

Prepending an apostrohe is not a good solution as it potentially breaks vlookups used for comparisons

Is there a way to do a search replace and preserve the resultant values as text, which they obviously are before removing the extension?

---

How the image names are being pulled in

```
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
    "URL;http://images.mysite.com/" & mfr, Destination:=Range("$E$2"))
    .Name = mfr
    .FieldNames = True
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .BackgroundQuery = True
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .WebSelectionType = xlAllTables
    .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
    .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
    .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
    .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
    .WebDisableDateRecognition = True
    .WebDisableRedirections = False
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With
```

---further information
Prior to the replace I am formatting the range as text

```
Selection.NumberFormat = "@"
Selection.Replace What:="_lg.jpg", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False
```

It would seem the `ReplaceFormat:=False` should do what I want but it doesn't

If format the range as `Selection.NumberFormat = "'@"` it fixes the dates issue and breaks the rest

Comment: If you control at the cell value then usually you can append "'" to the start of the string (cell(1,1) = "'" & somestring). In this case using querytables then pre formatting the column as text usually fixes it.

Comment: @pathDongle  added a little more regarding what I tried with the prepended apostrophe. I don't want o iterate too much through this checking for dates because it is typically 25-50K in images per report

Comment: Your code seems to come down to this example: `Sub test(): Sheet1.Range("A1").Value = "2496-6-4": Sheet1.Range("A1").Value = "'" & "2496-6-4": End Sub` - If column A:A is formatted as text then the first line will output as a string instead of a date. The second line will always output a string.

Comment: Just to be clear, you have to format the column as text BEFORE you output data.

Comment: @pathDongle The cell format is text the start, because it is a string with .jpg as an extension, but also am explicitly setting the format before doing the removal of that string portion. Checking before and after, all values not converted to dates maintain a text format. If I could concatenate the apostrophe on all values in a range without iterating cell by cell that would be best

Comment: Best thing then is to either output the querytable to csv/text file first and then re-import as text. Or drop querytables altogether and and scrape the html to an array and control the format before writing to Excel. There used to be an option in Excel to turn off date recognition but can't find it in Excel 2013?

Comment: @pathDongle thanks for the contribution of ideas

Answer (score 0):

before `Selection.NumberFormat` try adding `Selection.Value = "'" & Selection.Value` - this behaves different than formatting with `"'@"`

Comment: played with this quite a bit, but setting this for the selected range doesn't work. Might try iterating through for each cell, although you can't seem to prepend the apostrophe for the whole range at once